# Is it possible to get and remove something from a hash in Redis in one operation?

Tags: redis

I'm currently using Redis and doing an `HGET` followed by an `HDEL` to remove the field (and its value) from the hash once I've retrieved the value I need (which only needs to be used once).

Is there any way to do this in one operation (i.e. get a field and remove it from the hash)? I skimmed through the docs and couldn't find the right command.

Comment: Did you check the EVAL command with Lua script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Transactions](https://redis.io/commands#transactions) will do this. Use the MULTI command to start a transaction, within the transaction HGET what you want, HDEL it, and then EXEC.

You could also write a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands#scripting) to do this.